# Android: is View.onClick() method invoked on main UI thread?

Tags: android

Say that a user clicks on a Button. Is the resulting onClick() function invoked on the main UI thread of the activity?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes it is. And then you launch your crazy networking stuff in a background thread.